# Restfull API issue in cakephp 3.2

Tags: rest, cakephp-3.0

In order to create restful API in CakePHP 3.2. I have added the following code in [Restapi](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html)

config/route.php

```
Router::mapResources('recipes');
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

But I am getting an error.

```
Error: Call to undefined method Cake\Routing\Router::parseExtensions()
```

your help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Look at the top bar of the linked docs, it says "_CakePHP 2.x Cookbook_" and "_Version: 2.x_", ie you are looking at the one for wrong version. Check the 3.x docs: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/rest.html**, **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#resource-routes**

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

Don't forget the scope, notice the uppercase letter for Recipes, enter your extensions in an array.

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json']);
    $routes->resources('Recipes');
});
```